# How to process argument with dot in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, apache2, url-rewriting

I have this rule list in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-z&=\.\[\]{}%-]+)$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.incl$ - [R=404]
RewriteRule \.dist$ - [R=404]

RewriteRule ^handler/.*$ handler/handler.php? [L]
RewriteRule ^appsflyer/(.*)$ appsflyer.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^testlead/.*$ testlead/testlead.php? [L]
RewriteRule ^special/(.*)$ special/terminal.php$2 [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_[\]{}%&=-]+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) /link_handler.php?query=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯa-zA-Z0-9\s_\[\]\{\}\+%&=-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /link_handler.php?query=%1 [L,QSA]
```

When I try to pass an argument with dot in the URL:

```
http://myurl.ru/e96fxk&example.com
```

it returns:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /e96fxk&example.com was not found on this server.
```

How to add the "dot" symbol in this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯa-zA-Z0-9\s_\[\]\{\}\+%&=-]+)$
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last rules seems to be overly complicated. You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)query=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteRule . /link_handler.php?query=%1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try. Anyway, if there any case how to add this dot in a regexp expression mentioned above? I tried to add a dot as a . and \. elements, it doesn't work.

Comment: No, it's not in my case. I tried in my prior example with no dot in RewriteRule, actually, and the server just shows "Internal server error 501", if I add the "dot" from the RewriteRules, it just shows "The requested URL /e96fxk&example.com was not found".